# gradle: how to assemble a JBoss sar file

Tags: gradle, jboss, sar

Is there a gradle plugin that allows me to assemble a JBoss sar file including its jboss-service.xml deployment descriptor file? Thanks for any tips on how best to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I assembled a JBoss sar file using the Jar task:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            include '**/mypackage/service/*'
        }
    }
}

jar {
    extension = "sar"
    metaInf {
        from('src/mypackage/service') { 
            include 'jboss-service.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of extension within jar task could be used archiveName = "${project.name}.sar"